# Telescoping Series Sum with arctan

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I see that this is a question which was previously asked. However, the answer which was given doesn't seem to shed any light on what a sums terms tend to.

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\left(\arctan{(n+5)-\arctan{(n+3)}}\right)$$

So far, I have that, the first $n$ terms are given by

$$(\arctan{(6)} - \arctan{(4)})\qquad n=1\\
(\arctan{(7)} - \arctan{(5)})\qquad n=2\\
(\arctan{(8)} - \arctan{(6)})\qquad n=3\\
(\arctan{(9)} - \arctan{(7)})\qquad n=4\\
\vdots\\
(\arctan{(n+5)} - \arctan{(n+3)}) \qquad n=\infty\\\\$$

Furthermore, we have that we are left with $-\arctan{4}$ and $-\arctan{5}$ as these are the only terms, along with $\arctan{(n+5)} - \arctan{(n+3)}$ that do not cancel out.

Should our answer for this sum be $-\arctan{4}-\arctan{5} + \frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> With $\ds{N \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}}$:

\begin{align}
&\sum_{n = 1}^{N}\bracks{\arctan\pars{n + 5} - \arctan\pars{n + 3}} =
\sum_{n = 3}^{N + 2}\arctan\pars{n + 3} -
\sum_{n = 1}^{N}\arctan\pars{n + 3}
\\[1cm] = &
\bracks{\sum_{n = 3}^{N}\arctan\pars{n + 3} + \arctan\pars{N + 4} + \arctan\pars{N + 5}}
\\[5mm] - &\
\bracks{\arctan\pars{4} + \arctan\pars{5} + \sum_{n = 3}^{N}\arctan\pars{n + 3}}
\\[1cm] \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ N\ \to\ \infty}{\to}\,\,\, &\
\bbx{\ds{\pi - \arctan\pars{4} - \arctan\pars{5}}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

The telescoping partial sum gives
$$\arctan(n+5)+\arctan(n+4)-\arctan(5)-\arctan(4)$$
hence the sum of the series is
$$\pi-\arctan(5)-\arctan(4).$$

Comment: Why did you add the two $\frac{\pi}{2}$? Don't they cancel each other as we have the terms of our sum being $$\arctan{n+5} - \arctan{n+3} \to \lim_{n\to\infty}\arctan{n+5} -\lim_{n\to\infty}\arctan{n+3} \to \frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}=0 $$?

Comment: Have a closer look to the simplification I got: there remains a *sum* of two arctangents.

Comment: Apologies for being dense, but I still don't see the limit of, $\arctan{(n+5)} - \arctan{(n+3)}$ being anything other than 0. We have the sum terms being in pairs, our last $n$ terms in the sum being $\ldots+(\arctan{(n+5)}-\arctan{(n+3)})$. Am I missing something? Edit: How exactly did you go about obtaining the sum of two terms which are positive? @FelixMarin used notation I have yet to become familiar with.